# Looking for a proper way to combine JQuery DataTable and Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, out-of-memory

I'm recently using jQuery DataTable Plug-in to generate the result on my web side. I found out that [datatables.net](http://www.datatables.net) provides server-side features to generate a table with Ajax calls(Mine is JSON type). Now I'm using Ajax call and DataTable plug-in separately but sometimes if I request an Ajax call that can be returned a super large dataset from SQL database, jQuery DataTable can't handle it or an OutOfMemoryExeception is thrown. Here's my Ajax and DataTable code and both work properly:

```
$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        datatype: 'json',
        url: "url/url",
        data: {
            "Data1": data1,
            "Data2": data2,
            "Data3": data3,
            "Data4": data4,
            "Data5": data5,
        ...
        },
        success: function (data) {  
            var DataTable = $('#DataTable').dataTable({
                data: data,
                dom: '<"top"Bif>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">B',
                buttons: [
                    'excel', 'pdf'
                ]
            }
        );
        },//end success
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, throwError) {
                alert('failed')
        }//end error 
    });//end ajax
```

I'm looking for a way to put an ajax call inside of DataTable function and use some feature like `deferLoad()` to process the partial data rows while the full data table is generating. So below is the conception I tried follow the example from [datatables.net](http://www.datatables.net):

```
var DataTable = $('#DataTable').dataTable({
                  "serverSide": true,
                  "ajax": {
                         "url": "data.json",
                         "type": "POST",
                         "data":{
                               "Data1": data1,
                               "Data2": data2,
                               "Data3": data3,
                               "Data4": data4,
                               "Data5": data5,
                                ...
                                }       
                          }
                   "dataSrc": data,// I can't get a callback data from this code.
                   "deferLoading":10,

                    dom: '<"top"Bif>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">B',
                        buttons: [
                            'excel', 'pdf'
                        ]
                    });
```

But it didn't work in this way and it didn't even make an Ajax call to the server-side. Can somebody help me to make this code correct?

By the way I'm using ASP.Net MVC controller as the middle layer to communicate with Ajax and SQL server.

Comment: The `"dataSrc"` callback should be placed _inside_ the ajax struct.

Answer (score -1):

Your out of memory error suggests that on the server side the query being issued is returning all the data in your table, rather than just a page.

You may find it helpful to use my .NET wrapper for the Datatables library: http://aspdatatables.azurewebsites.net/

It provides

- MVC infranstructure for model binding
- viewmodel for defining your table's settings, rendering and plugin config
- a binding to map the datatable to an IQueryable datasource

[image]